# MySQL recurring event issue

Tags: mysql

I have two events one of them is programmed to work at 9AM of every day, the other is 10AM of every day. Problem comes when the first event starts, then the second dont work. Event Scheluder is turned ON, I'm using wampserver.
Here is my Code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`servidoranim`@`%` EVENT `ACTTICKETS9AM`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 9 DAY_HOUR STARTS '2018-04-01 00:00:00' ENDS '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
  UPDATE tickets set tickets.Estatus = 1
  where tickets.Estatus = 0 and date(tickets.FechaTicket) = date(now()) and Min_Sorteo = 1 ;
```

And second One

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`servidoranim`@`%` EVENT `ACTTICKETS10AM`
 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 DAY_HOUR STARTS '2018-04-01 00:00:00' ENDS '2018-05-01 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
  UPDATE tickets set tickets.Estatus = 1
  where tickets.Estatus = 0 and date(tickets.FechaTicket) = date(now()) and Min_Sorteo = 2 ;
```

PD:Sorry for my English

Comment: Well both EVENT SQL codes are almost indentical so we can rule out syntax errors,  logical errors and acces errors. "Problem comes when the first event starts, then the second dont work." Makes me wonder how large is the ticket table does the first update run for more then a hour and cancels the second event from running of not. And did you verify the information_schema.EVENTS table ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-table.html )  if the second event was really created?

Comment: Well my table 'Tickets' just have 14 rows... I'll add that the events sometimes work sometimes dont work, Must I to be logged in with my user  to get it working? the event is created and is 'Running' on Show events query